# Deflate Compression Algorithm Implemented in High Level Language?

Tags: algorithm, compression, deflate

There are lots of implementations of the Deflate *decompression* algorithm in different languages. The decompression algorithm itself is described in RFC1951. However, the *compression* algorithm seems more elusive and I've only ever seen it implemented in long C/C++ files.

I'd like to find an implementation of the compression algorithm in a higher level language, e.g. Python/Ruby/Lua/etc., for study purposes. Can someone point me to one?

Answer (score 1):

Pyflate is a pure python implementation of gzip (which uses DEFLATE).
http://www.paul.sladen.org/projects/pyflate/

Edit: Here is a python implementation of LZ77 compression, which is the first step in DEFLATE.

https://github.com/olle/lz77-kit/blob/master/src/main/python/lz77.py

The next step, Huffman encoding of the symbols, is a simple greedy algorithm which shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Pyflate implements the *decompression* algorithm, which as I said I have found lots of implementations of. I'm looking for the *compression* algorithm.

Comment: @Muchin: Huh, don't know how I missed that. Well, the compression algorithm is explained pretty well in the wikipedia article, to the point that I feel like I could probably implement it.